# Select / deselect dropdown option with JS on iOS 6.x (iPad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

I'm creating dynamic drodown using html `<select>` tag with attribute `multiple` and first option selected by default:

```html
<select multiple="multiple" size="1">  
    <option value="" selected="selected">All</option>  
    <option value="1">One</option>  
    <option value="2">Two</option>  
</select>
```

User taps option `One` for instance and then supposed behaviour is to deselect the `All` option and select the `One` option.

When iPad browser open native UI for dropdown I am able to catch touch events from dropdown control (code snippets from my plugin):

```js
this.$el.on('change', this.selectOption, this);
```

and manipulate options to deselect them in the way below:

```js
selectOption: function(e){
    var opts = element.find('option');  
    opts.each(function(idx, opt){  
        $(opt).prop('selected', false);  
    });  
}
```

### The problem

Option properties are set to `false` properly BUT visually in iPad's dropdown UI selected options remain unchanged - which may confuse user.
The changes in UI are applied after **Done** button in dropdown is tapped. Next opening shows all options deselected which is OK but little bit late ;-).

### The question

Is this possible to select/deselect options in the way where user taps one option and the other one is being deseleted realtime in native iPad dropdown?

Comment: I have the same problem. Still no luck?

Comment: Don't need each() there just do opts.prop('selected', false);

Comment: Apple said that they believe this has been fixed in iOS 7.1 beta5. I will wait for release and see.

Answer (score 1):

When we trigger a `<select>` in IOS it will use it's own internal browser control, beyond our ability to style.

It respects the `multiple="true"` attribute and acts accordingly.

The question is the equiv to asking : *"how can I make my browsers toolbar blue when I click on my webpage button"*

It is not clear from the question why

1. You set `mutliple="true"`
2. Then set the `size=1`
3. Then try to make it behave like a single `select` with javascript,
   only allowing one select.

---

I suspect that all you actually need is to remove the `multiple = "true"` attribute and maybe increase the size ( if you want all options visible )

```
<select size="3">  
    <option value="" selected="selected">All</option>  
    <option value="1">One</option>  
    <option value="2">Two</option>  
</select>
```

Then the native iOS controls can behave as you want.

For all other solutions , look into ditching the select ( or hiding it ) and create a custom javascript control made from `<ul><li>`'s ,or similar, to populate the values behind the scenes.

Comment: My client wants native ios multiselect with first option deselecting the rest of the options so there is no workaround in my case.

Comment: @HappyCoder, Gotya, like a kind of "clear selected"  button? At best How about `if(first selected) { un focus/blur the select; do the clearing; then refocus the select }` - just thinking off top of my head

Comment: I tried this workaround before and it works partially. Blur works. But focusing the select back doesn't work on iOS. It will work only if user triggers the real click/touchend.

Comment: hmm might need a small delay ? like setting a timeout  before the re .focus() - `setTimeout(function() { select.focus(); },600);` ( all very horrid huh! )